# Civievent - Billing fields

Tags: civievent, localisation, translation

Is it possible to change the labels for the billings fields when people are signing up for an event.

In the swedish translation of the fields: "First name, middle name and last name" they are called the same. Which makes it difficult for users to know what to write.

Example (translated from Swedish)
Billing adress 1 (mandatory)
Billing adress 2
Billing adress 3 (mandatory)

I have searched a lot of forums to find out how to change this. But it seems impossible. Should the translation be updated in Transifex or should it be made in the local installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to CiviCRM StackExchange Kim!

If you think that the translation should be changed for all users that use Swedish as a language in CiviCRM (e.g. because it is wrong or yours is better) you should update the strings in transifex.

This would imply that you create a free account there and ask to become part of the Swedish translation team. Once you changed the translation in transifex you will need to update your translation locally. You can find information on transifex in the [CiviCRM Wiki](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Pushing+new+strings+to+Transifex).

If you only want to change the translation for yourself, you should use the function for word replacement in CiviCRM, which you can find at yourdomain.org/admin/options/wordreplacements?reset=1

On the left side you will need to enter the original (English!) string, on the right side, the one you want to use (in Swedish).

Comment: Thank you Fabian! I have signed upp Transifex and started out helping in the Swedish team.